# R - Problem with rbind -> duplications of columns that have same name and format

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

recently I was confronted with a problem in RStudio when using rbind to add a data table to another. Assume the two data tables have two columns with exactly the same name and format (I have checked this with str()).
But when I want to bind them (Code table3<-rbind(table1, table2,fill=T)) either it duplicates the columns so that in the resulting table3 there a two columns with exactly the same name (the first one has entries for all rows coming from table1 and the second one for all rows of table2) or it has the name of the column only once but all the entries of rows coming from table2 are NA.
Both is very annoying, and also a new problem, because I used exactly the same code earlier and it was working perfectly well. The RVersion I'm using is R.4.1.1. Am I overlooking something? Or might there be some bug in this version?

Thanks very much for your help.

Table1 looks like:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7P6u.png).
Table2 looks like:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcz8y.png).

[Structure and error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xph50.png)

Comment: can you provide an example of the data that causes this problem?  at a guess the variable names aren't exactly the same.  you could try `intersect(names(table1), names(table2))` to check that they do really have the names in common

Comment: intersect(names(table1), names(table2)) gives exactly the names of table1 and table2

Comment: so this cannot be the problem. what I observed is that the problem arises after performing some aggregation-steps. So I start with table1 and perform some data manipulation on table2 which originally is just a copy of table1 and one of those steps is an aggregation table2 <- table2[,.(column1=sum(column1)),by=group.cols]. After this step some of the variables do not work in the rbind any longer. But it's also not every column that is affected from the problem

Comment: Some more information: when I try rbind(table1,table2) without fill=T the following error message is sent:
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Column 7 ['column7'] of item 2 is missing in item 1. Use fill=TRUE to fill with NA (NULL for list columns), or use.names=FALSE to ignore column names.
->so perhaps you are one the right track with the column names, but it has to be something in the background

Comment: this is unrelated to rstudio. also please add a reproducible example so others can help

Comment: Because names(table1) as well as names(table2) have "column7" included

Comment: I'm struggling with reproducing the problem as the code to get there is very large and the best would be to just upload a part of the two datasets that I want to bind, but as I can see this isn't possible. Is there any possibility that the names that are displayed differs from them that R internaly works with in the background?

Comment: -> Also see images in the problem description

Comment: I wonder if it's a problem with the umlauts?  What happens if you try names(table1)==names(table2) in your dummy data?

Comment: > names(table1)==names(table2)
[1] TRUE

Comment: `I'm struggling with reproducing the problem` ... you don't need to share the code to produce the data, just share a few rows of each table. Use `dput`, it is unambiguous, and if there's an `attribute` or other property of each table that is not obvious on the console, `dput` should still include it. Regardless, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: I don't think it's the umlaut itself, `rbind(data.table(Rechtsträger="a"),data.table(Rechtsträger="b"))` works. So the problem is something else, and (rephrasing what has been requested twice before me) without actual usable representative data in a reproducible question, this is unlikely to be resolved (quickly if at all).

Answer (score 0):

try to use merge(), e.g.:

```
table3 <- merge(table1,table2, by.x = 'names of table1', by.y = 'names of table2')
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but I don't want to join them horizontally but just vertically add some rows to the other one (they have exaytly the same column names and formats). I'm just wondering why it does not work in the approved way any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure that the encoding is the same on both.

Reproducible examples.

### Encoding on the column names

```r
quux1 <- quux2 <- data.table(Rechtsträger="a")
rbind(quux1, quux2)
#    Rechtsträger
#          <char>
# 1:            a
# 2:            a
Encoding(names(quux1))
# [1] "unknown"
Encoding(names(quux1)) <- "latin1"
rbind(quux1, quux2)
# Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
#   Column 1 ['Rechtsträger'] of item 2 is missing in item 1. Use fill=TRUE to fill with NA (NULL for list columns), or use.names=FALSE to ignore column names.
```

One fix? Copy the encoding:

```r
Encoding(names(quux2)) <- Encoding(names(quux1))
rbind(quux1, quux2)
#    Rechtsträger
#          <char>
# 1:            a
# 2:            a
```

### Encoding on the contents

I don't think this is the problem, as it is producing a different (though similar) error.

```r
vec <- "Rechtsträger"
quux1 <- data.table(Rechtsträger=vec)
Encoding(vec)
# [1] "latin1"
Encoding(vec) <- "UTF-8"
Encoding(vec)
# [1] "UTF-8"
quux2 <- data.table(Rechtsträger=vec)
rbind(quux1, quux2)
# Error in nchar(x) : invalid multibyte string, element 2
```

Similar fix:

```r
Encoding(quux2[[1]]) <- Encoding(quux1[[1]])
rbind(quux1, quux2)
#    Rechtsträger
#          <char>
# 1: Rechtsträger
# 2: Rechtsträger
```

---

Note to future self: my assumption that the output from `dput` is perfectly unambiguous has found its flaw:

```r
quux1 <- quux2 <- data.table(Rechtsträger="a")
Encoding(names(quux1)) <- "latin1"
dput(quux1)
# structure(list(Rechtsträger = "a"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
# "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000004501ef0>)
dput(quux2)
# structure(list(Rechtsträger = "a"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
# "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000004501ef0>)

identical(deparse1(quux1), deparse1(quux2))
# [1] TRUE
identical(Encoding(names(quux1)), Encoding(names(quux2)))
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that helps a lot and almost solves the problem. The only question that remains is why the encoding changes when performing an aggregation, i.e. tableX <- tableY[,.(column1=sum(column1)),by=group.cols]? Afterwards, the encoding of some of the group.cols is not the same in TableX as in tableY. Is there any possibilty to keep it persistent?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the change in column name encoding with a simple by-group aggregation.